# Express Handlebars callback function required

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, visual-studio-2017

I've been trying to use handlebars with express but I've been getting this error in the node.exe console stating that a callback function is required, any help?

app.js
http://pastebin.com/eR7aWYMe

Comment: I forgot this,  index.js: http://pastebin.com/jaHTSr8t

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the express generator? The way they have it set up is like so, after running with option `--hbs`:

`app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`

Just make sure you have hbs pulled into your node modules, and you should be good to go.

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: I got Router.use() requires middleware function but got a undefined.